# Chinese Input Stopped working in ubuntu 18.04LTE

Tags: ibus, input, input-method, chinese

I had Chinese input with IBUS working for a long time.  Recently the Chinese input started having some problems. When the problem occurred a week or two weeks ago, the input method works, shows the candidates, input  my choices, then after a few Chinese characters, it stopped mapping my choice number into Chinese character, just put the number into the document.

But now the input method completely stopped working, doesn't even switch to the Chinese input mode.

I removed and reinstalled Chinese, IBUS, restarted so many times without any success.

What else can I do?

Comment: I use sogou input method. Needs a bit of config but generally works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `ibus-libpinyin`, it might be related to a [recent version upgrade](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus-libpinyin/+bug/1768166). Maybe the cached history is corrupted somehow, and in that case you can make it work again if you open a terminal window and run this command:

```
rm ~/.cache/ibus/libpinyin/*
```

Comment: 非常感謝！ Thank you so much!

Comment: @Guangliang: Great to hear that it fixed it. Actually the version update was made to avoid crashes, since the previous version of `ibus-libpinyin` crashed a lot. Hopefully you had bad luck, and it will now work more reliably going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the fcitx?

You can try the method in this link, it may work: https://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/help.php

Comment: If it helps, kindly  accept it, thank you!

Comment: I almost did, but I saw someone posted that installing fcitx made his computer unable to boot, so I stopped.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  But Gunnar's solution works for me.  I'll stay on ibus for now.

Comment: When promoting your favorite input method, you should be aware that Fcitx doesn't work well on a standard Ubuntu desktop with GNOME. So on other desktop environments you can choose between IBus and Fcitx, but standard Ubuntu is designed for IBus only.

Comment: 原来是济南大学的好朋友啊。我去过那边，西门。欢迎参加AskUbuntu ！